# omp_get_max_threads() returns 1 in parallel region, but it should be 8

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm compiling a complex C++ project on Linux which uses OpenMP, compiled with CMake and GCC 7.
The strange problem I'm encountering in this particular project is that OpenMP is clearly working, but it thinks that only 1 thread is supported, when it should be 8. However, if I manually specify the number of threads, it does indeed accelerate the code.

```
logOut << "In parallel? " << omp_in_parallel() << std::endl;
logOut << "Num threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
logOut << "Max threads = " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;

logOut << "Entering my parallel region: " << std::endl;

//without num_threads(5), only 1 thread is created
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(5) 
  {          
      #pragma omp single nowait
      {
          logOut << "In parallel? " << omp_in_parallel() << std::endl;
          logOut << "Num threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
          logOut << "Max threads = " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
      }
  }
```

Output:

```
[openmp_test] In parallel? 0
[openmp_test] Num threads = 1
[openmp_test] Max threads = 1
[openmp_test] Entering my parallel region: 
[openmp_test] In parallel? 1
[openmp_test] Num threads = 5
[openmp_test] Max threads = 1
```

What makes it even stranger is that a simple test OpenMP program directly correctly reports the maximum number of threads as 8, both inside and outside a parallel region.
I've been combing through all the CMake files trying to find any indicator of why this project behaves differently, but I've turned up nothing so far. There is no mention of `omp_set_num_threads` in any of my project files, and I can confirm that `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not declared. Furthermore, this problem never happened when I compiled the same project on Windows with MSVC.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

(EDIT: I've expanded the code sample to show that it is not a nested parallel block)

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K

OS: Manjaro Linux 17.0.2

Compiler: GCC 7.1.1 20170630

_OPENMP = 201511 (I'm guessing that means OpenMP 4.5)

Comment: Can you add specific platform information to your question (OS, hardware, compiler, OpenMP runtime, etc.)? Can you also try outputting `omp_in_parallel()` and `omp_get_num_threads()` before your parallel region? Can you also verify that OMP_NUM_THREADS is unset in your enviornment? Do you observe different behavior if you set it?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the info you suggested. I confirmed that the code outside the parallel region is not in a parallel region and `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not declared.

Comment: Can you try adding a call to `getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS");` from <cstdlib> to the start of your program to ensure it returns NULL? Also, can you expand your code snippet to be complete (i.e., like how @FlashMcQueen wrapped it in `main()`), and confirm the same behavior? This will help us to rule out some library interfering with threading.

Comment: `getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS")` is null. As for the "complete snippet", I've already mentioned that this problem does not occur in a simple command-line program which only tests OpenMP. What's more, setting OMP_NUM_THREADS before running has no effect. I guess that means the problem is coming from a third-party library?

Comment: What's more, setting OMP_NUM_THREADS in the environment does not affect `omp_get_max_threads`.

Comment: Does the value change when you explicitly do `omp_set_num_threads`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program behaves exactly as if omp_set_num_threads(1) was called before.

Considering this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "omp.h"
int main() {

omp_set_num_threads(1);

std::cout << "before parallel section: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "Num threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Max threads = " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;

//without num_threads(5), only 1 thread is created
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(5) 
  {          
      #pragma omp single
      {
          std::cout << "inside parallel section: " << std::endl;
          std::cout << "Num threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
          std::cout << "Max threads = " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
before parallel section: 
Num threads = 1    
Max threads = 1
inside parallel section:  
Num threads = 5
Max threads = 1
```

When I run it by setting the number of threads by 4 instead of 1 (8 on your machine), the output is as expected:

```
before parallel section: 
Num threads = 1
Max threads = 4
inside parallel section: 
Num threads = 5
Max threads = 4
```

Have you tried to call omp_set_num_threads(8) at the begining of your code? Or have you set the number of thread to 1 before your program (for example by inside a function calling this...)?

One other explanation could be that openMP API doesn't find it necessary to have more than one thread as only a single section is implemented inside the parallel section. In this case try to add some code that could be executed by several threads to run faster (i.e incrementing all the values of a large array of integers or calling omp_get_thread_num()) outside the single section but inside the parallel section and the number of threads should be different. Calling omp_set_num_threads only sets the upper limit for the number of threads used.

Comment: That makes sense, but what on earth could be calling `omp_set_num_threads`? I did a full search and it does not occur in my code.

Comment: Then if you are sure omp_set_num_threads(1) is not called, try to add omp_get_thread_num outside the single section and inside the parallel section. (second explanation)

Comment: Already tried that. Without setting num_threads manually, `omp_get_thread_num` is always 0.

Comment: Hum outside the pragma omp single section this is weird

Answer (score 1):

The values you are seeing inside the parallel region seem correct (assuming that `OMP_NESTED` is not true). `omp_get_max_threads()` returns the maximum number of threads that you might obtain if you were to go parallel form the current thread. Since you are already inside a parallel region (and we're assuming that nested parallelism is disabled) that will be one.

> 3.2.3 omp_get_max_threads
>
> Summary
> The omp_get_max_threads routine returns an upper bound on the number of threads that could be used
> to form a new team if a parallel construct without a num_threads
> clause were encountered after execution returns from this routine.

That doesn't explain why you see the value one outside the parallel region, though. (But it does answer the question in the title, to which the answer is "one is the correct answer").